# Ninject + ASP.NET MVC + InRequestScope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a problem with the Ninject.

My binding rules:

```
this.Bind<ISphinxQLServer>().To<SQLServer>();
this.Bind<IMySQLServer>().To<SQLServer>();

this.Bind<ISQLLogger>().To<StandardSQLLogger>()
    .InRequestScope();

this.Bind<DatabaseConnections>()
    .ToMethod(x => ConnectionFactory.GetConnections())
    .InRequestScope();

this.Bind<SQLServer>().ToSelf()
    .InRequestScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connections", Kernel.Get<DatabaseConnections>())
    .WithConstructorArgument("logger", Kernel.Get<ISQLLogger>());
```

Where

**SQLServer, ISphinxQLServer and IMySQLServer are:**

```
public class SQLServer: ISphinxQLServer, IMySQLServer
{
    public DatabaseConnections Connections { get; internal set; }
    public ISQLLogger Logger { get; internal set; }

    public SQLServer(DatabaseConnections connections)
    {
        this.Connections = connections;
    }

    public SQLServer(DatabaseConnections connections, ISQLLogger logger)
    {
        this.Connections = connections;
        this.Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

I want that each user request to my asp.net mvc site creates a single SQLServer, a single ISQLLogger and a single DatabaseConnections. But my solution dont work. What am I doing wrong? =(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `WithConstructorArgument`. Resolving the parameters to the constructors of your injected objects is part of what Ninject does for you. So the definitions should look more like this:

```
this.Bind<SQLServer>()
    .ToSelf()
    .InRequestScope();

this.Bind<ISphinxQLServer>()
    .ToMethod( x => x.Kernel.Get<SQLServer>() );

this.Bind<IMySQLServer>()
    .ToMethod( x => x.Kernel.Get<SQLServer>() );

this.Bind<ISQLLogger>()
    .To<StandardSQLLogger>()
    .InRequestScope();

this.Bind<DatabaseConnections>()
    .ToMethod(x => ConnectionFactory.GetConnections())
    .InRequestScope();
```