# Ninject InRequestScope not creating new instance for each web request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am using ninject in my mvc application with AspNet Identity

In my global asax I have the following line of code

```
kernel.Bind<IIdentityManager>().To<IdentityManager>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("conn", idConnString);
```

Whenever a new request is made to the controller this therefore should create a new instance of the above class.

However this is not happening. Break points show that the constructor for the above class is only called once when the website loads and is never being hit again when I refresh the page or make a new request (it is injected into a class that is called on every page request to check the claims and thus authorise or deny the user access to the page they requested). Because of this the db connection context which underpins the identitymanager remains the same and never reloads on request. Thus it never picks up any changes to the claims that have happened externally to the website which is what would happen if a new instance of IdentityManager was created on each request as I would expect it to given the above binding.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT to add more code. (note I've removed code not relating to this particular problem to make it shorter)

My Global.asax

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
      {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        kernel.Bind<IVariables>().ToConstructor<Variables>(context => new Variables(AppSettingKeys.NRDAWebServer)).InRequestScope();

        var variables = kernel.Get<IVariables>();


        var masterPassword = VBHelperCore.Encryptor.EncDec.Decrypt(File.ReadAllBytes(AppSettingKeys.ConfigSettingsKeys.ConfigLocation + AppSettingKeys.SQLConnection.NRDAMasterUserName),
                AppSettingKeys.HexString);
        var s3ConnString = @"Data Source=" + variables.Get(AppSettingKeys.SQLConnection.NRDAMasterSQLServer, null) + @";Initial Catalog=" + variables.Get(AppSettingKeys.SQLConnection.NRDAMasterDB, null) +
                                                                            ";User ID=" + variables.Get(AppSettingKeys.SQLConnection.NRDAMasterUserName, null) + ";Password=" +
                                                                            masterPassword +
                                                                            ";Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
        var idConnString = s3ConnString;

         kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationFilter>().To<NrdaAuthenticationAttribute>().InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<IIdentityManager>().To<IdentityManager>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("conn", idConnString);

        kernel.Bind<INrdaClaimsTransformer>().To<NrdaClaimsTransformer>().InRequestScope();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
```

This essentially loads configuration variables to get the connection string with passwords and then binds a new instance of IdentityManager with the connection string passed to its constructor.

I have defined an ActionFilter

```
public class NrdaAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    [Inject]
    public INrdaClaimsTransformer ClaimsTransformer{ private get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public ILogger Log { get; set; }
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
            if ((user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated))
            {
                ClaimsPrincipal currentPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
                ClaimsPrincipal tranformedClaimsPrincipal = ClaimsTransformer.Authenticate(string.Empty, currentPrincipal);
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = tranformedClaimsPrincipal;
                HttpContext.Current.User = tranformedClaimsPrincipal;
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Security error" + ex.Message, null);
        }
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {


    }



}
```

All the controllers then have so this filter is called everytime you access any controller (so on every request)

```
[NrdaAuthentication]
```

The filter uses the kernel bound Claims Transformer

```
public class NrdaClaimsTransformer : ClaimsAuthenticationManager, INrdaClaimsTransformer
{
    [Inject]
    public IIdentityManager IdentityManager { private get; set; }

    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {

        var ret = !incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
             ? base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal)
             : DressUpPrincipal(incomingPrincipal);
        return base.Authenticate(resourceName, ret);
    }

    private ClaimsPrincipal DressUpPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {



        var user = IdentityManager.GetByUsername(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        return null //code removed to simplify example
    }
}
```

Obviously I've cut a lot of code out to simplify but due to the ninject bindings all being set to `InRequestScope()` I would expect the constructor of `IdentityManager` to be called on each new request. It however isn't. A breakpoint shows it's only called when the website first starts and never again after hence it must be using the same instance with every web request which it shouldn't

EDIT 2

Ok I think I've found the problem. It seems because that InRequestScope doesn't work within a custom authorisation attribute. Or indeed any of the other scope functions I've tried. I assume this is because the attribute instance is loaded into memory for the user's session and thus the injected class never expires so it doesn't need to be reloaded by ninject. When I do a test by calling the injected class using a controller and in the action it works fine. For now I will just need to load a new instance of the identitymanager each time in the attribute instead of the ninject version

Comment: Which version of Ninject are you using?

Comment: I'm using the following nuget packages: ninject v3.2.2, Ninject.MVC5 v3.2.1, Ninject.Web.Common v3.2.3, Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost v3.2.3 and Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolverv0.1.4758.24814. I admit I don't know if all of these are needed as I inherited the project from someone else

Comment: Ok, there is an issue with a previous version of Ninject ragarding InRequestScope. You have to provide more code if you want any help, I guess..

Comment: Cheers. I've updated the original post with all the code I think is relevant

Comment: As per this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492858/ninject-asp-net-mvc-inrequestscope?rq=1) maybe you could try having the string injected by putting it in the container.

Comment: Originally it used `ToConstructor` instead of `WithConstructorArgument`. `kernel.Bind<IIdentityManager>().ToConstructor<IdentityManager>(context => new IdentityManager(idConnString)).InRequestScope();` I switched to see if it made any differences.

Comment: The problem isn't the string injection or even what the class itself does. That's just the effect of the problem. The main issue is that despite using InRequestScope the break point for the bound class only gets hit once and is never called again when I make a new request. Hence it is always using the same instance which it shouldn't from what I understand of InRequestScope

Comment: Yeah but due to the nature of DSL type implementations, you can never be sure how each step affects your configuration. Have you tried using a different DI framework? Structuremap, LightInject, Unity

Comment: Ok I think I've found the problem. It seems because that InRequestScope doesn't work within a custom authorisation attribute. Or indeed any of the other scope functions I've tried. I assume this is because the attribute instance is loaded into memory for the user's session and thus the injected class never expires so it doesn't need to be reloaded by ninject. When I do a test by calling the injected class using a controller and in the action it works fine. For now I will just need to load a new instance of the identitymanager each time in the attribute instead of the ninject version

Comment: So inconclusion. Any ninjected instance used in a filter never refreshes itself with each new request. It remains for the users continued session. Any ninjected instance in the controller class itself is refreshed each request

Comment: I guess you need a FilterProvider to acheive what you want. This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35164362/1236044